# "gentle landscape" - Wbat does it mean?

Tags: meaning

what is gentle landscape ? I've got a short explanation like "a landscape with nothing extreme or threatening about it" but I find it insufficient. Could you please define it broadly?

Comment: It sounds like a rather bland landscape. If you [edit] your question to provide more context to the phrase (e.g. the sentence you found it in), the community may be able to help you more.

Comment: The term has a literal meaning (fields, or undulating hills, not steep cliffs or boulder-strewn terrain which is difficult to traverse) and also a figurative meaning, where the "landscape" is not a real landscape but a metaphor for peacefulness, lack of strife and contention, such as "As the election drew closer, negative TV ads began to mar the gentle landscape that characterized the early days of the campaign".

Comment: @Lawrence I'm not sure  it'll be usefull to provide context regarding that phrase but anyway here you are :   "Chianti is a very large portion of Tuscany, famous for its wine, its oil, for its gentle landscape, of rolling hills and vineyards, considered an example of the perfect coexistence and integration between man and nature."

Comment: @TRomano Would this phrase be only said about countryside landscape or   city, town landscapes might also be included in this definition?

Comment: We could use the word **cityscape** of the city when it is viewed from afar;  the phrase "urban landscape" refers to the streets from the perspective of someone inside the city.

Comment: @TRomano I mean , could any cityscape be referred to as "gentle landscape" or this could only be said about countrysides?

Comment: The phrase 'gentle urban landscape' is about as likely as "mild Siberian winter". I suppose it might have been appropriate of Philadelphia as envisioned by William Penn. According to his original city plan, every fourth block was to be a park.

Comment: @CavidHummatov That's quite useful, and communicates many of the things LawrenceC discussed in his answer. His first and last points (*pleasant to view and experience*) are particularly relevant to your context, but the other points also fit well. It would be good to [edit] the question to include your descriptive paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

A gentle landscape is one with no threatening aspects, as opposed to a dramatic landscape with rugged hills or mountains.
This is an example of a gentle landscape, the English Cotswolds [link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cotswolds+photos&client=tablet-android-pega&prmd=imsvn&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&fir=tWNIHKDDccstdM%253A%252C17JYtSLVrHYApM%252C_%253BMS8yH-0eB2DoTM%253A%252C17JYtSLVrHYApM%252C_%253BM9bTD-vgLYcnvM%253A%252Cv3K5zsjWPWjyAM%252C_%253BQa1_csiUivV9vM%253A%252C981HrcOk7VifnM%252C_%253BTeGikX6TYcTxJM%253A%252Cb92X7kbyrNETEM%252C_%253BXlvhSaRNEgYIWM%253A%252CywGSA_RqqagFwM%252C_%253B2bAD5fQ33i_xTM%253A%252CKXhOZ3Ead2lgbM%252C_%253BShGDomC_lTo9NM%253A%252CTivu3FkNwI44dM%252C_%253Bm1c4pLlCPyUklM%253A%252CSydaCyolBcM_yM%252C_%253B8B1A0sO5egkIfM%253A%252COL7sZnW9M8-TqM%252C_%253BZP_yHEXYzlMcaM%253A%252CZRgidKfZDMHtdM%252C_%253BV9ggY05AMbQJTM%253A%252CzFE1ZLXsM85-FM%252C_&usg=__uEYNoXO287Sr8A9PfzDnj1VLz-I%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj10Yff6oDPAhWH0RoKHZ_1DywQ7AkINw&biw=960&bih=600#imgrc=r_jChSXJRg8PuM%3A)

This is an example of a dramatic landscape, part of the Scottish Highlands.
[link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=snowdonia+photos&client=tablet-android-pega&prmd=imnv&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&fir=AGr8RkUVWWrhUM%253A%252C_lZ9ghwUNRur2M%252C_%253BUudnXO-vUFyLSM%253A%252C_lZ9ghwUNRur2M%252C_%253BUEvgfLr5XUdWiM%253A%252CfvsCV3T87yfmdM%252C_%253Ba8JFgGGzbuEgEM%253A%252C9Qq2gV00BXoaxM%252C_%253BoWU-gSZijUc1wM%253A%252CfvsCV3T87yfmdM%252C_%253B-gY90lBM78Z5XM%253A%252ChYd045SR1JuwbM%252C_%253BIv16NYJg7Uk24M%253A%252C9nU647P1XbIj0M%252C_%253BROK27Cr7mxVC4M%253A%252Cz1pgf6mTQwdEsM%252C_%253By75c8pe2WNNZKM%253A%252COhTymVSw6Ed1eM%252C_%253BOFe4xdnwPMFkoM%253A%252CtBR-70_8Bm-CaM%252C_%253BdtBLYvR84z4r8M%253A%252C7iiNly-VRq8LhM%252C_%253BCFgRikZMuPbmaM%253A%252CCWQnzPhjC1fcnM%252C_&usg=__nDVbD_RDX0miNTPN8wBxEGJkMWI%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHrPyk64DPAhWBlxoKHRVbCK4Q7AkINw&biw=960&bih=600#tbm=isch&q=scottish+highlands&imgrc=RZFbAvWXP5DVlM%3A)

Comment: does these both(dramatic or gentle landscspe) involve weather conditions as well , say, dramatic landscape has the view of thunders with torrential rain and high winds ,conversely, gentle has nice, sunny weather. Or these terms have nothing to do with the weather circumstances at all?

Comment: Nothing to do with the weather as far as I'm concerned. A dramatic landscape is dramatic on a calm sunny day and a gentle landscape is still gentle even if it's being battered by a hurricane. Storm damage to the gentle landscape could change its character until the damage was repaired or repaired itself but that would be a semi-permanent change.

Comment: Thanks alot you all.   Answers were of great help in understanding   broadly.

Answer (score 2):

*Gentle landscape* is not a well-known saying, but looks/sounds like "flowery" language that is trying to evoke an emotional response from you.  So it should not be taken literally, and it could technically mean a number of things depending on the mood the writer or speaker is trying to convey.  It can't be completely understood apart from its surrounding text or speech.

It could mean:

- A landscape that is pleasant to look at.
- A landscape that doesn't have harsh attributes, or is being contrasted with another thing that has harsh attributes, such as "The gentle landscape was a welcome change from the dirty junkyard."
- A landscape that's easy to walk or travel upon, e.g. not hilly.
- A landscape that doesn't have a lot of complexity to it, maybe just a few manicured bushes, etc. and nothing very elaborate.
- A landscape that is comforting and refreshing to look at or be in.